# Return results from multiple table fields

Tags: php, sql

I've got returns results from a query but I would like it to return multiple results, this is the current query:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE isLeased = 0 AND featured = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $qry) or die('-1' . mysqli_error());
```

What I would like is for it to return those results, as well as the results for:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE isLeased = 0 AND propertyType = 'For Sale' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $qry) or die('-1' . mysqli_error());
```

But if I just add the second section of code below the first one it only returns the results of the first one.

How could I tell it to return results based on a couple of tables?

Comment: join 1,2,3,... table .
not multiple table fields in query.

or result query push array .

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UNION` query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM properties
    WHERE isLeased = 0 AND featured = 1
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 9
) t1
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM properties
    WHERE isLeased = 0 AND propertyType = 'For Sale'
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 3
) t2
```